# Update in mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an application where I use spring framework and I use mongoDB as database. I have a collection which is indexed by email. The fields are:

```
{
    email: <email>
    profile: {
        name: <name>
        age: <age>
        customMap: {
        }
    }
}
```

This is the document:

```
@Document(collection = "user")
class User {
    String email;
    Profile profile;
}

class Profile {
    String name;
    int age;
    Map customMap;
}
```

The use case is that email field is unique. So when a request comes in with an existing email, I need to update the document with new profile. I'm able to insert a new document with `mongoOperations.save` call. But while doing an update, if I pass customProfile with new map, I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
```

As an error. But if I try to update only `age` field, it updates successfully. I'm facing problem only with using a map and I'm using a `HashMap`.

This is the code for update:

```
Update update = new Update();
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile.setAge(10);
Map customMap = new HashMap();
customMap.put("name", "value");
profile.setCustomMap(customMap);
update.set("profile", profile);
mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, User.class);
```

If I comment out `profile.setCustomMap(customMap);` then it updates successfully. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580529/how-do-i-update-fields-of-documents-in-mongo-db-using-the-java-driver/12103403#12103403
Seems this could be helpful.

Comment: @ArunAK In the above example they're not using spring. The only problem I'm facing is when I introduce a map.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the email in your User object. Otherwise the DB won't know which User to update.

Comment: user object has email set. Query : query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(user.getEmail()));
The worst part is it doesn't show what is null in the stacktrace. All I get is "this argument is required; it must not be null"

Comment: You can use MongoDB management tool to see your database. I use it http://robomongo.org/