# Update Mongo document field from Grails app

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, updates

I have a requirement where I have to check in the database if the value of a boolean variable(crawled) is false. If so I have to set it to true. I am finding the record based on the value of a string variable(website). I referenced [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580529/how-do-i-update-fields-of-documents-in-mongo-db-using-the-java-driver) but it didn't help. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

I tried this:

```
def p = Website.findByWebsite(website);
if(p['crawled'] == true) {
    println "already crawled"
} else {
    mongo.website.update( p, new BasicDBObject( '$set', new BasicDBObject( 'crawled', 'false' ) ) )
    println "updated object"
}
```

It gives me an error `No such property: mongo for class: cmsprofiler.ResourceController`

My domain class is as follows:

```
  class Website{
    String website
    User user
    Boolean crawled
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    static constraints = {
        website( url:true, unique: ['user'])
    }
    static hasMany = [resource: Resource]
    static mapping = {resource cascade:"all-delete-orphan" }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Posting it here in case anyone else has similar requirement.

```
@Grab(group='com.gmongo', module='gmongo', version='0.9.3')
import com.gmongo.GMongo
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ResourceController {
    def mongo = new GMongo()
    def db = mongo.getDB("resources")
    def p = Website.findByWebsite(website)
    if(p['crawled']==false){
    db.website.update([crawled:false],[$set:[crawled:true]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using

```
Website.mongo.update(...)
```

or let the framework inject it:

```
class ResourceController {
  def mongo

  def list(){
     mongo.website.update(...)
  }

}
```

Comment: 1st approach: Still throws the error: No such property: mongo for class: cmsprofiler.Website

2nd approach: No such property: website for class: com.gmongo.GMongo

Comment: are you using hibernate along with mongo?

Comment: try putting `static mapWith = 'mongo'` into your domain class