# updating a value in an array in mongodb from java

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have couple of documens in mongodb as follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54901212f315dce7077204af"),
"Date" : ISODate("2014-10-20T04:00:00.000Z"),
"Type" : "Twitter",
"Entities" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : 4,
        "Name" : "test1",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 20,
            "Neutral" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "ID" : 5,
        "Name" : "test5",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 10,
            "Neutral" : 1
        }
    }
]
```

}

Now I want to update the document that has Entities.ID=4 by adding (Sentiment.Value+4)/2 for example in the above example after update we have 12.

I wrote the following code but I am stuck in the if statement as you can see:

```
 DBCollection collectionG;
   collectionG = db.getCollection("GraphDataCollection");
    int entityID = 4;
    String entityName = "test";
    BasicDBObject queryingObject = new BasicDBObject();
    queryingObject.put("Entities.ID", entityID);
    DBCursor cursor = collectionG.find(queryingObject);

    if (cursor.hasNext())
    {
        BasicDBObject existingDocument = new BasicDBObject("Entities.ID", entityID);
        //not sure how to update the sentiment.value for entityid=4
    }
```

First I thought I should unwind the Entities array first to get the value of sentiment but if I do that then how can I wind them again and update the document with the same format as it has now but with the new sentiment value ?

also I found the this link as well :
[MongoDB - Update objects in a document's array (nested updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array)

but I could not understand it since it is not written in java query,
can anyone explain how I can do this in java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12103403/1254903

Would this help?

Comment: No because it is not a simple update I need to get the current value of sentiment for that entityid and add it by for example 4 and divide it by 2

Comment: I think the depicted document in your question has a different structure than what you actually propose to do. There is no field such as `sentiment.value`, with which performing the mentioned operations we get a value of 12. Can you check if the document structure is correct?

Comment: @BatScream Sorry yes you are right I updated the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps:

- Get all the `_id` of the records which contain a Entity with sentiment
  value `4`.
- During the `find`, project only the entity sub document that has
  matched the query, so that we can process it to consume only its
  `Sentiment.Value`. Use the positional operator([$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update)) for this purpose.
- Instead of hitting the database every time to update each matched
  record, use the [Bulk](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BulkWriteOperation.html) API, to queue up the updates and execute it
  finally.

Create the Bulk operation Writer:

```
    BulkWriteOperation bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
```

Find all the records which contain the value `4` in its `Entities.ID` field. When you match documents against this query, you would get the whole document returned. But we do not want the whole document, we would like to have only the document's _id, so that we can update the same document using it, and the Entity element in the document that has its value as 4. There may be `n` other Entity documents, but they do not matter. So to get only the Entity element that matches the query we use the positional operator [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/).

```
    DBObject find = new BasicDBObject("Entities.ID",4);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("Entities.$",1);
    DBCursor cursor = col.find(find, project);
```

What the above could would return is the below document for example(since our example assumes only a single input document). If you notice, it contains only one Entity element that has matched our query.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54901212f315dce7077204af"),
        "Entities" : [
                {
                        "ID" : 4,
                        "Name" : "test1",
                        "Sentiment" : {
                                "Value" : 12,
                                "Neutral" : 1
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Iterate each record to queue up for update:

```
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        BasicDBObject doc = (BasicDBObject)cursor.next();
        int curVal = ((BasicDBObject)
                     ((BasicDBObject)((BasicDBList)doc.get("Entities")).
                     get(0)).get("Sentiment")).getInt("Value");
        int updatedValue = (curVal+4)/2;
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id",doc.get("_id"))
                         .append("Entities.ID",4);
        DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set",
                          new BasicDBObject("Entities.$.Sentiment.Value",
                                             updatedValue));
        bulk.find(query).update(update);
    }
```

Finally Update:

```
    bulk.execute();
```

You need to do a `find()` and `update()` and not simply an `update`, because currently `mongodb` does not allow to reference a document field to retrieve its value, modify it and update it with a computed value, in a single update query.

Comment: Thanks a lot yes it worked, just a quick question : can you explain DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("Entities.$",1); more? what is for example 1 in that?

Comment: @HamedMinaee - Please see my updated answer. To know more about positional operators click on the `$` symbol in my answer.(There are tow, go through both)

Comment: Now I got it but why 1 why not 2 ? still I do no know what that 1 point to?

Comment: The allowed values for projection are `0` and `1`, `0` will exclude the field, `1` will include the field. It is **not** an index.